# what should be the return type of a method returning list

Tags: apex, soql

```
public static List<string> searchForContacts (String l1, String p1) {  
    List<Contact> c = [select name from contact where lastname=:l1 and mailingpostalcode=:p1];   
    return c;
}
```

**I'm getting the following error:**

> error: illegal conversion from list to list

Answer (score 2):

Ther is no plain List return type. You have to explicitly set the list type as in

```
Public List<Contact> myMethod(){}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to change your signature from `List<String>` to `List<Contact>` in order for that code to compile.

Comment: If it did, mark it as accepted so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, occasionally it can be useful to generalise the type e.g.

```
public static List<SObject> searchForContacts (String l1, String p1) {
    if (...) { 
        return [select name from contact where lastname=:l1 and mailingpostalcode=:p1];
    } else {
        ....
    }   
}
```

or even:

```
public static List<Object> searchForContacts (String l1, String p1) {  
    if (...) { 
        return [select name from contact where lastname=:l1 and mailingpostalcode=:p1];
    } else {
        ....
    }   
}
```

But most of the time best to use explicit types as in the other answers here.